# Vue Router Data persistance

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have an app that requires a persistent connection (uses WEBRtc) The VUEX store can change based on a data transfer.

In my routes I have (for simplicity sake) 2 navs in my router view

```
            <b-dropdown-item
              href="#"
              @click="$router.push({name: 'marriagesection', params: {id:Math.floor(Math.random() *10 )}})"
            >Previous Marriages</b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item
              href="#"
              @click="$router.push('/applic/children',s,e)"
            >Children / Grandchildren</b-dropdown-item>
```

When I navigate between them, I loose the data.

I have tried putting a :key on the router-view, explored beforeEnter, and created a mutation that I subscribe to to get the info initialized again - this works if I console log it, but it doe not update the DOM. I have used :keys in the do after getting the info and still doesn't work. I have more than 3 days on this problem and there is a severe lack of documentation on this issue.

I have MUCH to much to keep all of the information in a store, and the DOM has to respond to changes in other views, making use of VUEX almost impossible, or so large it almost would become useless.

Please help